# Python, Approximate time Stamp into a 30 sec Perios

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

Given a time stamp in the data frame like 7/22/2019  9:57:36 AM , I would like to approximate to a 30 Sec window resolution.  9:57:36 AM would become  9:57:30 AM, 9:57:16 AM would become 9:57:00 AM.

```
I would like to try **3 Solutions** to round to 30 seconds window, 
> 1) Approximate to previous 30 seconds window 
> 2) Approximate to next 30 seconds window, 9:57:36 to become 9:58:00 
> 3) Approximate to nearest 30 seconds window 9:57:36 -> 9:57:30 also 9:57:16 become 9:57:30
```

Better if the solution could directly work on Pandas DataFrame

Comment: Hi, [pandas.Timestamp.round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.round.html) should do it

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Pandas time round", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: you want `.floor`, `.ceil` and `.round` for 1,2 and 3 respectively. See the [`DateTime  Methods`](http://cs.indstate.edu/CS617/PANDAS/api.html#datetimelike-properties) section.